# echo append onto existing row, continue on the row

Tags: shell, echo

How can I append the string `:/etc/simmmerin/bin/` into a file `filename` using echo command onto an existing row. Can't get it working.

```
echo ":/etc/simmerin/bin/" >> filename
```

It just appends in the bottom of the file instead of continuing on the row I wanted it to be. I would like to use `echo` instead of going into each files in `vim` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The file already has a newline at the end, terminating the final line. Anything append to it, therefore comes on another line. You'll need to overwrite the final newline, which you can't do with just a `>>` redirection. Probably easiest to use `sed`:

```
$ seq 1 4 | sed -e '$s,$,stuff/to/append,'
1
2
3
4stuff/to/append
```

To have `sed` modify a file in-place, use

```
sed -i -e '$s,$,stuff/to/append,' filename
```

(The dollar signs have two meanings there. The first `$` is an address that controls what line the next command runs, here it means the last line. The second `$` is regex notation for the end of line.)

---

To append to some other line than the last, replace the first `$` with either a line number or a pattern match. This would append a string to any line containing `foo`:

```
sed -i -e '/foo/ s,$,stuff/to/append,' filename
```

Note that I used commas here as separators for the `s` command. Slashes would be more common, but the text to be added contains them. The `s` command allows (almost) any character to be used.

If you have slashes in the pattern used to find the correct line, you can use something like `\,foo,` as the address, i.e. start with a backslash and use whatever separator is convenient.

Comment: is is sed or seq? seq 1 4 | sed -e? or sed 1 4 | sed -e?

Comment: @johnsnow, ah, sorry, that's confusing. `seq` is a utility that outputs a **seq**uence of numbers. I only used it here to produce some input. `sed` is the **s**tream **ed**itor that does the work. I added the command to have `sed` directly modify a file.

Comment: Cant get it working if I wanted to specify a row for it to append onto.

Comment: @johnsnow, ah, yes, I thought you meant the last. You'll need to add a condition before the `s`, edited

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify an existing file, you can use `sed` command.

Given that you have both your string to append, and the line number you want to insert the string:

```
mystring=":/etc/simmerin/bin/"
lineno=10
```

Insert the string at the *beginning* of the line:

```
sed "${lineno}s,^,${mystring}," file
```

Insert the string at the *end* of the line:

```
sed "${lineno}s,\$,${mystring}," file
```

Insert the string *before* the line:

```
sed "${lineno}s,^,${mystring}\n," file
```

Insert the string *after* the line:

```
sed "${lineno}s,\$,\n${mystring}," file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file already has a `newline` at the end of file.
Newline character is 1 byte large: use the `truncate` command to shrink the file by one byte and then append at the end of file.

```
truncate -s -1  filename && echo ":/etc/simmerin/bin/" >> filename
```

Answer (score -2):

instead of echo use printf, this one do not add "\n" by default

please note that printf is a command of bash, so make sure your shell support it

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  When should they use `printf`?  If the last line of the file contains a newline at the end, using `printf` will not solve anything.  Also, _all_ shells on a POSIX system understands `printf`.